# How to order a query by column if some of its values are null?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two tables `posts` and `posts_replies` I queried all posts and order them by timestamp (post time).
Now I want to do the following :
Any time a user make a reply for any post I want to put that post at the top of the wall 
so I did get the max replies' timestamp of each post and order the posts using the max timestamp of the replies of specific post.

The problem is that some posts does not have any replies so the max timestamp_of_replies of this post will be NULL so I want to know : Does it possible to order the result by timestamp_of_replies when it is not null and by post_timestamp when it is NULL.

My query :

```
SELECT 
    posts.*,
    u1.id as user_id, 
    u1.avatar, 
    u1.username as poster_username, 
    u2.username as posted_username , 
    posts.timestamp, 
    f1.recent_reply_time
FROM 
    posts 
INNER JOIN 
    users u1 
    ON posts.poster_id = u1.id  
INNER JOIN 
    users u2 
    ON posts.posted_id = u2.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        max(timestamp) as recent_reply_time, 
        post_id 
    FROM 
        posts_replies 
    GROUP BY post_id) f1 
    ON f1.post_id = posts.id
order by 
    f1.recent_reply_time DESC
```

Note : `order by f1.recent_reply_time, posts.timestamp DESC`  did not give me right results

Comment: You can consider the first post as a reply. In this way, you will ever have a not-null timestamp.Else, you could use an IF statement to ignore null cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has an [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function, that you may also use in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY IF(column IS NULL, othercolumn, column)
```

in your case it would be:

```
ORDER BY IF(f1.recent_reply_time IS NULL, posts.timestamp, f1.recent_reply_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SORTING` is easily readable and maintainable, if you make it based on what you select. Better have some `sortkey` in your select and use it in `ORDER BY`.

i have used `COALESCE` to handle nulls. Makes ure sortkey atleast have one `NOT NULL` value, by using suitable arguments to COALESCE

```
 SELECT posts.*,
       u1.id as user_id,
       u1.avatar,
       u1.username as poster_username, 
       u2.username as posted_username,
       posts.timestamp,
       f1.recent_reply_time,
       COALESCE(f1.recent_reply_time,posts.timestamp) as sortkey
    FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN users u1 ON posts.poster_id = u1.id  
    INNER JOIN users u2 ON posts.posted_id = u2.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(timestamp) as recent_reply_time, post_id FROM posts_replies GROUP BY post_id) f1 ON f1.post_id = posts.id
    order by sortkey DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE:

```
SELECT posts.*, u1.id as user_id, u1.avatar, u1.username as poster_username, 
       u2.username as posted_username , posts.timestamp, f1.recent_reply_time
FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN users u1 ON posts.poster_id = u1.id  
    INNER JOIN users u2 ON posts.posted_id = u2.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(timestamp) as recent_reply_time, post_id 
               FROM posts_replies 
               GROUP BY post_id) f1 ON f1.post_id = posts.id
ORDER BY COALESCE(f1.recent_reply_time,[alternative value (CURDATE())]) DESC
```